# unable to set global variable in subscribe function

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to set service response in a variable for use in view  my TS file is as follow

MenuService is custom service and geMenus() is function to fetch all menus from database

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { MenusService } from '../menus.service'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header1',
  templateUrl: './header1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header1.component.css'],
  providers:[MenusService]
})
export class Header1Component implements OnInit {

  menus=['Login','Register','Subscribe'];
  primeryMenus:any; 
  //menus1=['Home','Matches','Players','Teams','Tournaments','Contact Us','About Us'];
   constructor(private translate: TranslateService,private _ser:MenusService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getMenu();
  }
  getMenu(){
    this._ser.getMenus().subscribe(res=>{
      this.primeryMenus = res;
      console.log(this.primeryMenus) // output is json object ( getting correct output )
    });
    console.log(this.primeryMenus) // output is undefined

  }

  switchLanguage(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
  }


}
```

how to set primaryMenu in subscribe observable

Comment: subscribe is async operation so the last console.log is excute first

Comment: What kind of error do you get ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code

```
this._ser.getMenus().subscribe(res=>{
  this.primeryMenus = res;
  console.log(this.primeryMenus) // output is json object ( getting correct output )
});
console.log(this.primeryMenus) // output is undefined
```

This is the fundamental nature of subscribe. The callback is executing *after* all the sync code is done.

## Fix

Use the value *only* after the subscribe is invoked.

Comment: It nice to see you here mr @basarat

Answer (score 2):

Observables are asynchronous. You put the second `console.log()` outside the subscription. There it gets processed long before the Observable returns a value. Do it only this way:

```
getMenu(){
    this._ser.getMenus().subscribe(res=>{
          this.primeryMenus = res;
          console.log(this.primeryMenus) // output is json object ( getting correct output )
});

// never put a console(log) here if you want to see the return value of the observable above as it processed long before the Observable returns a value.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just because the **response** you are getting from the service **after** the outer console log **execution**. So at that time it is showing undefined.
If you want to do/show something only if the response is received, better you call a function inside the subscribe method.

```
  getMenu(){
    this._ser.getMenus().subscribe(res=>{
          this.primeryMenus = res;
          this.doSomething();
});

doSomething() {
   console.log(this.primeryMenus);
  // Do something awesome
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In MenusService

```
/**
     * Method is used to get data
     * 
     */
    getMenus():  Observable<any> {
        this.requestURL = `url`;
        return this.http.get(this.requestURL);
    }
```

In Header1Component:

```
getMenu(){
    this._ser.getMenus().subscribe((res: any)=> {
      this.primeryMenus = res;
      console.log(this.primeryMenus);
    });
    console.log(this.primeryMenus) ;
  }
```